# Android SMS backup & restore

Tags: android, sms, android-contentprovider

I'm making one small Android app. App is able to read SMS from inbox and save it into xml file on sdcard. When I try to write SMS back to inbox by reading from xml file which was created earlier - it works perfectly on Emulator, but not working on Android device.

For SMS inbox I have used Content provider.

Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: I would suggest you to post some code.

Comment: maybe you need add this permission: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/> but explain better your question

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue ?